# TransferFunctionModel produces large coefficients

Tags: control-systems

First, I define the following transfer functions using `TransferFunctionModel`:

```
tfmGc[s_, a_, t_] := TransferFunctionModel[(1 + a*t*s)/(1 + t*s), s];
tfmGp[s_, k_] := TransferFunctionModel[k/(s*(s + 5)), s];
```

Next, the two transfer functions above are connected in series using `SystemsModelSeriesConnect`, and a unity feedback connection is established using `SystemsModelFeedbackConnect` to produce the open loop and closed loop transfer functions respectively:

```
tfmOLTF[s_, a_, t_, k_] := SystemsModelSeriesConnect[tfmGc[s, a, t], tfmGp[s, k]];
tfmCLTF[s_, a_, t_, k_] := SystemsModelFeedbackConnect[tfmOLTF[s, a, t, k]];
```

Finally, I evaluate `tfmCLTF` with the following parameters:

```
a1 = 0.166521;
t1 = 12.010533;
k1 = 9;

tfmCLTF[s, a1, t1, k1] // TransferFunctionExpand
```

Mathematica produces the following result:

[image: Result of tfmCLTF[s, a1, t1, k1] // TransferFunctionExpand]

**My question is**: Is there a way to change this so that the coefficients are not too large?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get rid of those large coefficients by using [`TransferFunctionCancel`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransferFunctionCancel.html).

```
tfmCLTF[s, a1, t1, k1] // TransferFunctionCancel // TransferFunctionExpand // Chop
```

> [image]

I'm not quite sure why it produces them in the first place.

(You may also consider using [`TransferFunctionFactor`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransferFunctionFactor.html) instead of [`TransferFunctionCancel`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransferFunctionCancel.html), because the latter will also cancel common pole-zero pairs. This does not happen in this case.)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! It worked!